# What is the negative omega squared in this function?

Tags: frequency, bode-plot, sinusoidal

[image]

I'm trying to draw a Bode plot for the transfer function, but I am confused on what the negative omega squared is supposed to be. Is it supposed to be the frequency with no phase angle? How can I get rid of the negative?

Comment: Sort of like in algebra, you do factorization to condense like-terms. Multiply it out and see what you get :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the \$-\omega^2\$ term comes from \$(j\omega)^2\$ which probably means double pole at the origin. Move the negative sign to the numerator and you'll get a gain of -400.

Answer (score 0):

Well, notice that:

$$\left(\text{j}\omega+100\right)^2=\left(\text{j}\omega+100\right)\left(\text{j}\omega+100\right)=\text{j}\omega\text{j}\omega+\text{j}\omega100+100\text{j}\omega+100\cdot100=$$
$$-\omega^2+200\text{j}\omega+10000$$

Answer (score 0):

It's already said. Your G has double pole in the origin i.e. the canonical realization of G contains 2 integrators cascaded with other blocks.

For example this block diagram (like infinite number of others) has your transfer function G:

[image]

It has 2 integrators, both have time constant =1/20 seconds. The order of the blocks can be changed.

Both integrators cause 90 degrees phase lag, total 180 degrees. It's there and stays. At frequency =0 the gain is infinite and the phase lag is 180 degrees. Infinite gain is there because in integrators the slightest amount of continuous DC input cumulates with no limits as long as the physical structure allows the integrating functionality. In practical systems there's all kinds of limitations which stop the integration to happen (like operating voltages, melting temperatures, available amount of material or room for motion, etc).

To draw the transfer function you must separately show that there's infinite gain at frequency =0. The actual curve can start from a frequency >0 so that the rest of the terms are visualized. The phase plot can start at frequency = 0. I guess there's some strict formal requirements given how to present things if this is a homework - An example "use log frequency scale and dB scale for gain to show clearly things like gain slopes decibels/octave".